# database connection cannot be made when same db is used by three web application

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat7

One db is been used by three web application two of them are little bit heavy traffic application while the third one in not traffic heavy application.

When I first use the third application which is an restful web service it works ok. but when I use it after using the the other two, all my application stops working

here is my hibernate config file for all three of the applications:

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">3</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">40</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="dynamic-update">true</property>
```

please advise!

log was big I have pasted here the relevant log as far as I think:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 155,938 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 155,938 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor245.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3829)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2449)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2629)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2713)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:5060)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(NewProxyConnection.java:881)
    at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.openConnection(AbstractBatcher.java:424)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3810)
    ... 56 more
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.ErrorCodeConverter.handledNonSpecificException(ErrorCodeConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.ErrorCodeConverter.convert(ErrorCodeConverter.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.openConnection(AbstractBatcher.java:427)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connect(JDBCContext.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1129)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:373)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:1562)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:1545)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1316)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:299)
    at com.csat.db.crud.QuestionCRUD.SearchQuestion(QuestionCRUD.java:56)
    at com.csat.rest.resource.SurveyRequest.getSurvey(SurveyRequest.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1483)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1414)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 71,198 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3567)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3456)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3997)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2468)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2629)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2713)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:5060)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(NewProxyConnection.java:881)
    at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.openConnection(AbstractBatcher.java:424)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:114)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:161)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:189)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3014)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3467)
    ... 58 more
```

Comment: Which error you received? May be pool size is not enough (hibernate.c3p0.max_size)

Comment: please tell what should by my hibernate.c3p0.max_size for al the three applications!

Comment: Can you check the db server side? Our DB servers also have a maximum simultaneous connections they allow. e.g. the server says "50 simultaneous connections is ok" and you connect with 6 apps and each wants 10 you run into trouble.

Comment: What OS are you running on ? Depending on your OS, you may be running out of open files, or, like stated before, mysql has exceeded the maximum amount of open connections. I dont believe c3p0 is the problem since your stacktrace points to sources/ lines after the c3p0 libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add params to you hibernate config:

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">0</property> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">0</property> 
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>
```